# Chrome not rendering SVG properly

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, svg, reactjs, rendering

Working on a D3, React, Redux web app and running into an interesting bug when rendering an SVG containing a bunch of rectangles.

**Application Summary**

1. We use a [D3 Partition Layout](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Partition-Layout) to generate a huge (~3000) list of nodes to set the appropriate layout attributes (x, y, dx, dy).
2. We use React/Redux for the rest of the application to store this state and ultimately render an SVG for the chart.

**Problem**

- Some nodes (rendered as rects) in the rendered SVG simply don't show up!

**Theories**

1. Originally, we thought we had a bug with how we were generating the rectangles, but this turned out not being the case (Rects exist in the dom with the right attributes).
2. We are rendering other things in addition to the rects, so we thought those were conflicting when the browser painted everything. That seemed to not be the case since we disabled all of these other items and we're still seeing the issues.
3. It could be a [browser bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=svg%20rect%20missing&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=ids) when it comes to rendering rects. Our app currently doesn't even render properly when on Firefox, so it may be something to do with how we are generating the SVG.

**Example**

Here are some examples of what we are talking about.

Here's an example of the chart being rendered properly with all of its nodes.
[image: A good chart]

Here's an example of the chart rendering with part of its nodes missing:
[image]

Here's an example of the same chart magically breaking after we alt tabbed a few times:
[image]

**Questions**

What we're looking for is any ideas from people more experienced with SVG rendering for what we could be looking into. There are a bunch of possibilities, but we're not sure which direction we should be looking into.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Sure I'll work on it.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/w197qs0h/. As far as minimal goes, this probably doesn't hit it, but other than arbitrarily deleting nodes, it's difficult to shrink it down further. No code besides the HTML is required. The SVG simply doesn't render properly. You can see similar situations to the ones I noted above by finding missing blocks in the chart.

Comment: I'd try drawing rects closer to the size you want i.e. stop giving them tiny widths/heights and remove the scale transforms as much as you can.

Comment: Interesting, that was an approach I was going to test. Why would this cause an impact, though? The inspector shows that the rect is positioned appropriately with the correct dimensions.

Comment: Because you're asking the browser to multiply numbers together and get an accurate result and it likely rounds at some point in some way you don't really want.

Comment: I found it hard pressed to accept that since there are cases where a rect half renders, which indicates that the browser had the right idea. Also, alt-tabbing causes it to work as well, which means that it "can" render properly. Though, definitely something to test out.